# How to insert radio button value which is have multiple radio name in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to making online quiz with codeigniter where there is a dynamic quiz with some subject. User can add the question and the multiple choice answer in each question. How can i get the value of each answer in each multiple choice answer on every question?

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('c_kuis/addKuisAnswer'); ?>
       <?php foreach($soalKuis as $row){?>
            <?php $jawab_array = array($row->pil_a,$row->pil_b,$row->pil_c,$row->pil_d);
            ?>
            <p><?=$row->soal?></p>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->id_soal?>" value="A">A.<?=$jawab_array[0]?></input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->id_soal?>" value="B">B.<?=$jawab_array[1]?></input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->id_soal?>" value="C">C.<?=$jawab_array[2]?></input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->id_soal?>" value="D">D.<?=$jawab_array[3]?></input><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="id_soal_kuis" value="<?=$row->id_soal?>"></input>
            <br><br>
       <?php } ?>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      <?php form_close(); ?>
```

and this is the code looks like when i try to inspect :

```
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban1" value="A">A.Hamster</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban1" value="B">B.Tiger</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban1" value="C">C.Shark</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban1" value="D">D.Lion</input><br>
            <br><br>

            <input type="radio" name="jawaban2" value="A">A.was</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban2" value="B">B.have</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban2" value="C">C.am</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban2" value="D">D.is</input><br>
            <br><br>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Here is my Controller looks like :

```
public function addKuisAnswer(){
    if($this->session->userdata('data_user')->level != 1){
        redirect('/c_user/login');
    }
    $id_soal_kuis = $_POST['id_soal_kuis'];
    $id_user = $this->session->userdata('data_user')->id_user;
    $answer = $_POST['jawaban']; //The Problem's here... I should put jawaban with id_soal. Because the answer named 'jawaban1','jawaban2' etc it will follow the id_soal. How can i insert it?
    $this->load->model('m_kuis');
    $this->m_kuis->createAnswerKuis($id_soal_kuis, $id_user, $answer);
     echo " <script>
                    alert('Jawaban Tugas Tersimpan!');
                    history.go(-2);
                    </script>"; 

}
```

Here is my model :

```
public function createAnswerKuis($id_soal_kuis, $id_user, $answer){
    $data = array(
        'id_soal_kuis'=>$id_soal_kuis,
        'id_user' => $id_user,
        'jawaban_kuis' => $answer            
    );
    $this->db->set('tgl_jawab', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    $this->db->insert('jawab_kuis', $data);
}
```

I want the table looks like this :[This is the picture of database table i made.I want to insert the data like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYoJW.png)

The problem is in Controller. How can my Controller post the value of radio button `name="jawaban<?=$row->id_soal?>"`in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this little change will helps you

```
 public function addKuisAnswer(){
        if($this->session->userdata('data_user')->level != 1){
            redirect('/c_user/login');
        }
        $id_soal_kuis = $_POST['id_soal_kuis'];
        $id_user = $this->session->userdata('data_user')->id_user;

        $this->load->model('m_kuis');
        $i=1;
    while(isset($_POST['jawaban'.$i]))
    {
         $answer = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];
//         var_dump($answer);
 $this->m_kuis->createAnswerKuis($id_soal_kuis, $id_user, $answer);
         $i++;
    }

         echo " <script>
                        alert('Jawaban Tugas Tersimpan!');
                        history.go(-2);
                        </script>"; 

    }
```

you can change radio button name in sequential order(because there is no need of id appending in radio button)

```
 <?php 
$i=1;
    foreach($soalKuis as $row){?>
            <?php $jawab_array = array($row->pil_a,$row->pil_b,$row->pil_c,$row->pil_d);
            ?>
            <p><?=$row->soal?>
    <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $row->id_soal?> name='id_soal'<?= $i ?>/></p>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$i?>" value="A">A.<?=$jawab_array[0]?></input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$i?>" value="B">B.<?=$jawab_array[1]?></input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$i?>" value="C">C.<?=$jawab_array[2]?></input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$i?>" value="D">D.<?=$jawab_array[3]?></input><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="id_soal_kuis" value="<?=$row->id_soal?>"></input>
            <br><br>
       <?php $i++;} ?>
```

Comment: This helps me a lot. Now my code is running properly!

Comment: Hey, can i ask one more question to you? i'm having a problem hope you can solve it.

Comment: where is your new question -@Hikaru18

Comment: Your answer above was work when my radio button name is jawaban1,jawaban2, jawaban3, jawaban4 etc it works when its id_soal is in sequential order. I found a problem when there is my radio button name isn't always in sequential order like this for example : jawaban3, jawaban4, jawaban6, jawaban7, jawaban10 etc. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I see! Thanks once again! your answer really helped me a lot

Comment: I want to improve this code. could you help me @ubm ? i want the database table look like this +-----------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| id_answer | id_student  | id_kuis |   answer    |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|         1 | 99999874465 |       7 | A,B,D,A,C,B |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-------------+.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235172/insert-radio-value-multiple-data-codeigniter-in-database-to-one-row 
 hope you can help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this the question you meant :

> How can i insert the value of radio button name="jawabanid_soal?>"in database?

or, how to read the value of the selected radio button and then insert it in the DB?

I will answer to both. To read the value of the answers you can go with `foreach` loop:

```
<?php 
$egabat= array();
foreach($soalKuis as $row){
        $egabat[$row->id_soal]= $_POST["jawaban".$row->id_soal];
} ?>
```

To insert the value in the DB, if this is MySql, then I recommend this very useful guide.

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: I've added my controller and model. If you have any ideas... please help me again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function insert($postdata)       //modelfunction for insert
{
$array(
$tablevalues=
'filed1'=>$_POST["jawaban".$row->id_soal],      // consider field1 as ur table field

);

$this->db->insert('table_name',$tablevalues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer... but i still find some errors

Comment: I've added my controller and model. If you have any ideas... please help me again.

Comment: Paste your code and error here. Than I can say something.

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `jawab_kuis` (`tgl_jawab`, `id_soal_kuis`, `id_user`, `jawaban_kuis`) VALUES (NOW(), '4', '1', Array)

Filename: D:\COLLEGE (TIF-UB)\xampp\htdocs\eschool\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0):

You may put the value of **$row->id_soal** in hidden with the name array field when submitting the form then get the values of radio button with dynamic ids that come from the hidden field.

```html
<?php 
$egabat= array();
foreach($_POST['hiddenfield'] as $idsoal){
        $egabat[$idsoal]= $_POST["jawaban".$idsoal];
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'm still find some error

Comment: I've added my controller and model. If you have any ideas... please help me again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to achieve this:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('c_kuis/addKuisAnswer'); ?>
   <?php foreach($soalKuis as $row){?>
        <?php $jawab_array = array($row->pil_a,$row->pil_b,$row->pil_c,$row->pil_d);
        ?>
        <p><?=$row->soal?></p>
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<?=$row->id_soal?>]" value="A">A.<?=$jawab_array[0]?></input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<?=$row->id_soal?>]" value="B">B.<?=$jawab_array[1]?></input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<?=$row->id_soal?>]" value="C">C.<?=$jawab_array[2]?></input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<?=$row->id_soal?>]" value="D">D.<?=$jawab_array[3]?></input><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_soal_kuis" value="<?=$row->id_soal?>"></input>
        <br><br>
   <?php } ?>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <?php form_close(); ?>
```

and in controller you will have these values in an array which can be retrieve like:

```
<?php
     foreach($this->input->post('jawaban') as $radio){
         echo $radio;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still running with some error

Comment: I've added my controller and model. If you have any ideas... please help me again.