# insert radio value multiple data codeigniter in database to one row?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a quiz online project i want the answer save like this in database

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| id_answer | id_student  | id_kuis |   answer    |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|         1 | 99999874465 |       7 | A,B,D,A,C,B |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

this quiz is multiple choice. So how can i insert the data of answer like that.

here's my view

```
 <?php echo form_open('c_kuis/addKuisAnswer',$atribut); ?>
                        <?php foreach($soalPG as $row){?>
                        <?php $jawab_array = array($row->pil_a,$row->pil_b,$row->pil_c,$row->pil_d);?>
                        <p><?=$row->no_soal?>.<?=$row->soal?></p>
                        <input type="hidden"name="id_soal<?=$row->id_soal_pg?>" value="<?=$row->id_soal_pg?>"></input>
                        <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->no_soal?>" value="A"> A. <?=$jawab_array[0]?></input><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->no_soal?>" value="B"> B. <?=$jawab_array[1]?></input><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->no_soal?>" value="C"> C. <?=$jawab_array[2]?></input><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?=$row->no_soal?>" value="D"> D. <?=$jawab_array[3]?></input><br>
                        <br><br>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="kuis_id" value="<?php echo $kuisPG->id_ks;?>"></input>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary submit" id= "submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                    </div>
```

and here's my controller

```
public function addKuisAnswer(){
        $kuis_id = $_POST['kuis_id'];
        $id_user = $this->session->userdata('data_user')->no_id;
        $i=1;
        while(isset($_POST['jawaban'.$i]))
         {
            $answer = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];
         }
        $this->load->model('m_kuis');
        $this->m_kuis->answer_PG($id_user,$kuis_id,$answer);
         echo " <script>
                        alert('answer saved!');
                        history.go(-2);
                        </script>"; 

    }
```

How can i edit my controller to input data as the example table above?

Comment: what is the result in `$answer`?

Comment: the result is the alphabet of the multiple choice for example when POST jawaban3 the the result of $answer will C for example

Comment: so you want to insert only that `C`  your db?

Comment: no..... i want jawaban1,jawaban2,jawaban3,jawaban4 etc.. can insert to db like this A, D, C, B

Comment: after getting data of array use array impload function Ex :: `$answer=implode(",",$answer);` add this after while loop

Comment: Try this `$answer = array();
while(isset($_POST['jawaban'.$i]))
         {
            $answer[] = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];
         }
         echo implode(",", $answer);` ans see `$answer` print comma seprated value or not?

Comment: i got error Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: add your model functions too-@Hikaru18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may helps you

```
public function addKuisAnswer(){
    $kuis_id = $_POST['kuis_id'];
    $id_user = $this->session->userdata('data_user')->no_id;
    $i=1;
    while(isset($_POST['jawaban'.$i]))
     {
       if($i == 1)
         {
           $answer = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];
          }
        else{
        $answer. =','. $_POST['jawaban'.$i];
       }
      $i++;
     }
    $this->load->model('m_kuis');
    $this->m_kuis->answer_PG($id_user,$kuis_id,$answer);
     echo " <script>
                    alert('answer saved!');
                    history.go(-2);
                    </script>"; 

}
```

We have another solution,using `explode` and `implode`

```
while(isset($_POST['jawaban'.$i]))
{
     $answer_array[] = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];

     $i++;
}
$answer = implode(',',$answer_array);
```

Comment: It works! i've tried your code at the first section and it works! thank you @ubm

Answer (score 1):

Since there will be only one answer for your question the name for your radio buttion should be same for all 4 options, so the user can select only single answer and you can easily get it in the post request.
and rest of your code is looks correct.

Comment: i'm sorry but my radio button name is all correct... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061074/how-to-insert-radio-button-value-which-is-have-multiple-radio-name-in-codeignite here's my problem before that problem has solved.. now i have a problem to insert all the answer in one row since in that problem i insert one answer in one row.

Comment: what is ur column data type

Comment: which column? for the jawaban$i  . i have varchar type

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
public function addKuisAnswer(){
    $kuis_id = $_POST['kuis_id'];
    $id_user = $this->session->userdata('data_user')->no_id;
    $i=1;
    while(isset($_POST['jawaban'.$i]))
     {
        $answer = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];
     }
    $this->load->model('m_kuis');

    // add this line to combine all the array values as a string
    $answer = implode(",",$answer);

    $this->m_kuis->answer_PG($id_user,$kuis_id,$answer);
     echo " <script>
                    alert('answer saved!');
                    history.go(-2);
                    </script>"; 

}
```

Comment: I follow this i got database error because answer is NULL

Comment: can you `print_r($answer);` and see the result before inserting into db?

Comment: i got Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: change `$answer = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];` to `$answer[] = $_POST['jawaban'.$i];` and try

Comment: i've tried that too... but i got the same error messege